# In Flutter widget testing, how to pause app to find suggested Finder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am following flutter widget testing as https://flutter.io/testing/#widget-testing.

It says that

> simply flutter run test/widget_test.dart to see your test run in your preferred runtime environment such as a simulator or a device. During a flutter run session on a widget test, you can also interactively tap parts of the screen for the Flutter tool to print the suggested Finder.

I am using flutter run test/widget_test.dart so that i can tap and get suggested finders. But I am not able to pause the test so that i can actually tap. The test runs and automatically ends. So that there are no widgets on the screen except Text('Test Finished').

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just set a breakpoint in the IDE on a line in the test.

Comment: I am not using an IDE, to run my tests, i am running it from the command line using the commen flutter run test/widget_test.dart. The test page does not metion how to debug the test except debugDumpApp() which just dumps the whole widget tree.

Comment: After your comment i also tried to use debugger() from https://flutter.io/debugging/, which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: No idea what you tried. You need to open the Observatory https://flutter.io/debugging/#dart-observatory-statement-level-single-stepping-debugger-and-profiler

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been almost 2 years since the question was asked, but anyway. `tester.idle()` helped me to pause an app.

```
testWidgets('idle', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    //
  );
  await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.bluetooth));
  await tester.pump();
  tester.idle();
});
```